# how to convert list to items in python spark

Tags: pyspark

My following code just generated a RDD which contains lists, and then transform the list to items via flatMap. But I think the following kind of stupid, do I have to write the function listToItem, and do I have to write the function printStr. Any optimization on the following code please.

```
def listToItem(inputList):
    return inputList
def printStr(tm):
    print tm

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sc = SparkContext(appName="Test Spark")
    rdd1 = sc.parallelize([[1,2,3],['a','b','c']])
    res = rdd1.flatMap(listToItem).foreach(printStr)
    sc.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first one just use identity (credit [Is there a builtin identity function in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8748036/6022341)):

```
>>> _ = lambda *args: args
>>> rdd1.flatMap(_)
```

For the second one import print function:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
```

and

```
>>> rdd1.flatMap(_).foreach(print)
```

but remember that it is useless (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25296061/6022341)