# Where is the logical 'or' equivalent in the 'operator' module?

Tags: python

Adding or multiplying  a large list of numbers in Python can elegantly be done by folding the list with the addition or multiplication operator:

```
import functools, operator
lst = range(1,100)
sum  = functools.reduce(operator.add, lst)
prod = functools.reduce(operator.mul, lst)
```

This needs the function equivalents of the operators `+` and `*` which
are provided by the [operator module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) as `operator.add` and
`operator.mul`, respectively.

If I want to use the same idiom with the operator `or`:

```
ingredients       = ['onion', 'celery', 'cyanide', 'chicken stock']
soup_is_poisonous = functools.reduce(operator.or, map(is_poisonous, ingredients))
```

... then I discover that `operator` doesn't have a function equivalent of the logical `and` and `or` operators (though it *has* one for logical `not`)

Of course, I can trivially write one that works:

```
def operator_or(x,y):
  return x or y
```

But I wonder: why are there no `operator.or` and `operator.and` in `operator`? Bitwise `and` and `or` are there, but not the logical ones.

Of course this is just a minor annoyance, and the answer may well be
the same as with [the missing identity function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748036/is-there-a-builtin-identity-function-in-python):
that *it is easy to write one*. But this holds for `*` and `+` as well, so why the difference?

Comment: `functools.reduce()` doesn't provide a way to signal that you want to short circuit the operation, so it doesn't seem like there would be a difference between logical vs bitwise `and`/`or`.

Comment: So what would a hypothetical logical-and function look like? Remember that it must only evaluate its right-hand side if necessary. (Before someone points it out: Yes, I suppose it could take the second argument in the form of a function to call. I'm not sure how much contortions that would require from the compiler, but apparently someone thought it not worth the trouble...)

Comment: @rchome - Exactly what I was thinking, all operands would be evaluated, which is not the same as `and` and `or` in most languages. (I don't do Python and struggle with how its documentation is organized, so couldn't readily find out if it's also true in Python, but it seemed likely. *Edit:* [found it](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations))

Comment: Yes, that is probably it (see my comment below timgeb's answer). Coming from Haskell, I was slow to realize that  Python is a [strict programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_programming_language)

Comment: @rchome There are differences. `1 and 2` is true but `1 & 2` is false. And `[1] | [2]` errors.

Comment: @Kelly `1 and 2` is in fact `2`…!

Comment: @deceze Can you clarify what you mean, why you're saying that?

Comment: @Kelly `1 and 2` returns the value `2`, not `True`, as stated or implied by you.

Comment: @deceze I did **not** state or imply that it's `True`. I said it's true. Which it is.

Comment: @Kelly *Truthy?*

Comment: @deceze What about that? That's an abominable word, and not official terminology. See for example [this recent issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue45346), where a few "truthy" that had crept in were immediately eradicated, without debate. Official terminology is true/false, as mentioned in that issue, also see the five links there.

Answer (score 4):

To wrap up all your helpful answers
and comments, in order of somewhat decreasing (to me) convincingness:

1. *the addition of `operator.or` would break an important promise made by the module*

   For all operators `<op>` that have function equivalents
   `operator.op` in the `operator` module, it is the case that `a <op> b` is equivalent to (i.e. can always, without changing program
   behaviour, replace or be replaced by) `operator.op(a, b)`. This
   equivalence is actually mentioned in the module docstring.  This is
   impossible to do for the operators `and` and `or` as their
   evaluation is [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) while Python function calls are always evaluated *after*  **all** of their arguments are.
2. *On the values `True` and `False`, `|` and `&`, hence also the existing (bitwise) `operator.and_` and `operator.or_`
   already return the same results (if they return at all, that is) as `or` and `and`*.

   If `is_poisonous()` returns either True of False (not an unreasonable requirement), I could use

   ```
   soup_is_poisonous = reduce(operator.or_, map(is_poisonous, ingredients), False)
   ```

   in the example from the original question. However, many Python
   programs conveniently use any "truthy" value as `True` in idioms like

   ```
   your_model_T_color = "black" or any_color_you_like
   ```

   using `|` or `operator.or_` instead of `or` here will result in a
   `TypeError` or, even worse, some unexpected value (if the operands
   are `int`s)
3. *The functions `any` and `all` can be used instead of
   `functools.reduce(operator.or, ....)`*

   I'm not convinced by this
   argument: `operator` functions are used in many more contexts than
   as a first argument to `reduce`. Moreover, `any` always returns
   either `True` or `False`, not the first truthy value:

   ```
   any([0,0,0,5,6,7]) # returns True
   reduce(lambda x, y: x or y, [0,0,0,5,6,7]) # returns 5
   ```

   so `any` and `reduce(operator.or` would not really be equivalent
4. *`any([x,y])` does the same (and more, as it accepts iterables) as `operator.or(x,y)` would.*

   That is not quite true (see above), `any([0,5])` returns `True` while `operator.or(0,5)` would return 5. Moreover, the number of arguments matters greatly if we use a function as an argument to another function like  `reduce()`

Answer (score 2):

`all` is short-circuiting logical-and.
`any` is short-circuiting logical-or.

No need to put versions that take exactly two arguments (instead of an iterable) into the `operator` module, I guess.

Comment: That there are excellent alternatives for the idiom `reduce(operator.or, ...)` doesn't make `operator.or` superfluous, as there may be other uses for such  a function. But that such a function  will necessarily behave differently from the operator (as Python _always_ evaluates function arguments before calling a function) is probably a good reason to leave it out and thus avoid confusion. Forcing me to write `operator_or` myself makes the difference explicit and is probably a wise design choice.

Comment: They don't do the same thing, though, always returning `True` or `False` instead of one of the operands.

Comment: `all` and `any` are not (and _cannot_) be short-circuiting. `any([x == 0, 1/x > 1])` will divide by zero if `x == 0`, while `x == 0 or 1/x > 1` will not.

Comment: @HansLub the functions any and all are understood to be [short-circuiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14730046/is-the-shortcircuit-behaviour-of-pythons-any-all-explicit). As you, I and everybody else knows function argument evaluation is never lazy in Python.

Comment: I think we are arguing about words here. As I understand it, when you
call `any()` short-circuiting, you mean that for any iterator `it`,
`and(it)` will call `it.__next__()` often enough, but no more, to
determine a return value. I call a function or operator
[short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)
if it evaluates just the arguments it needs to determine a return
value. Python's  `and` and `or` are short-circuiting in one sense of the
word, while `any()` and `all()` are short-cicuiting in another.

Comment: @HansLub sure. There's only one way functions can short circuit in Python, so there's no ambiguity in my statement. It's different in other languages.